# R Convert quoted numbers to numeric

Tags: r, type-conversion

Hi I have a table of characters that I am attempting to convert to numbers as so:

```
vec1 <- c("B","D","E","NA")
vec2 <- c("B","D","E","NA")
vec3 <- c("B","C","E","NA")
vec4 <- c("B","D","E","NA")
vec5 <- c("B","NA","E","E")
vec6 <- c("B","NA","NA","NA")
mat1 <- (cbind(vec1,vec2,vec3,vec4,vec5,vec6))

mat1
#     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
#[1,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
#[2,] "D"  "D"  "C"  "D"  "NA" "NA"
#[3,] "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "NA"
#[4,] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" "E"  "NA"

mat1[mat1 == "NA"] <- 0
mat1[mat1 != 0] <- 1

mat1
#     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
#[1,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#[2,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
#[3,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0" 
#[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0" 

mat2
#     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
#[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
#[2,]    2    2    2    2    1    1
#[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    1
#[4,]    1    1    1    1    2    1

mat2 <- sapply(as.data.frame(mat1), as.numeric)
```

This is OK to work with, i.e. I can subtract 1 from all the values to get to the original quoted values, but how do I simply change the quoted values to numeric values?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: `mat1[] <- as.numeric(mat1)`

Comment: @BondedDust, that won't work.

Comment: You can specify `stringsAsFactors = F`, i.e, `mat2 <- sapply(as.data.frame(mat1, stringsAsFactors = F), as.numeric)`

Comment: Huh, color me surprised. This works : `class(mat1) <- "numeric"`

Comment: Nice @BondedDust. I was also thinking `mat2 <- as.numeric(mat1); dim(mat2) <- dim(mat1)`, but yours better

Comment: `mat2 <- sapply(as.data.frame(mat1), function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` works also, but I can't seem to trace the step at which each individual columns became factors. It is disturbing that you can typecast with `class()` -> "class" in R.

Comment: What about `(mat1!="NA")+0` ?

Comment: @BondedDust, Yes Great!! Thanks, Please could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite @Vlo's displeasure (and incorrect orientation of the assignment arrow) the change in the class of a vector from character to numeric is fairly safe. His code is needlessly complicated because the matrix was of class `character` rather than being a `factor`, so conversion to data.frame and then needing to use `as.character` was unnecessary. R matrices cannot be factors, since matrices are not supposed to have any attributes other than a `dim` vector, and dimname-lists (and the "core" atomic vector that carries its own class). There is a `class<-` function:

```
 class(mat1) <- "numeric"   # See the help page:  ?`class<-`
```

It also works for character to logical:

```
> m <- matrix( c('TRUE','FALSE'), 4,4)
> class(m) <- 'logical'     # assignment of `as.logical` to `m[]` fails.
> m
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you wanted to use an apply function, this would succeed:

```
> mat2 <- apply(mat1,2, function(x) as.numeric(x) )
> mat2
     vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4 vec5 vec6
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
```