# How to convert all columns of a df from characters to numeric?

Tags: r

I would like to convert all columns of a df from character to numeric.

df example:

```
 A      B      C     D
"1"  "10.2"  "0.2"  "8"
"5"  "2.1"   "0.5"  "6"
"3"  "4.6"   "0.3"  "7"
```

Convert character values in all columns (A,B,C,D) to numeric. Thanks!

Comment: hmm...checking back on this question 3 hours later and I see 3 answers.  I guess SO is a homework site.  huzzah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of ways of doing this.  I like this approach by `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% map_if(is.character, as.numeric) 

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: num  1 5 3
 $ B: num  10.2 2.1 4.6
 $ C: num  0.2 0.5 0.3
 $ D: num  8 6 7
```

Comment: I had to run this script following to get a data.frame:                                     df = as.data.frame.list(df)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
 df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.character(x)) as.numeric(x)
                          else x)
```

If we know that all columns are 'character' and needs conversion

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [R Convert quoted numbers to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654549/r-convert-quoted-numbers-to-numeric)

Basically you can use the `apply()` function inconjunction with `as.numeric()` to convert the numbers as string to numeric.

Comment: Specifically: apply(df, 2, as.numeric)

Answer (score 0):

I like doing it this way.

```
data <- apply(df, 1, fun(x) as.numeric(x))
```