# How to convert all columns where entries have length ≤1 to numeric?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I have a data frame with ~80 columns, and ~20-40 of those columns have single-digit integers that were stored as characters. Other character columns are complete sentences (so, `length >>> 1`), and so get coerced to `NA` if I try `mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)`.

I would like to transform those efficiently, and based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399774/how-to-convert-all-columns-of-a-df-from-characters-to-numeric), I was hoping for something like this:

`df %>% map_if(is.character & length(.) <= 1, as.numeric)`

However, that doesn't work. I'm hoping for a `tidy` solution, maybe using `purrr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best function for these situations is [type_convert()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.3.1/topics/type_convert), from `readr`:

"[`type_convert()` re-converts character columns in a data frame], which is useful if you need to do some manual munging - you can read the columns in as character, clean it up with (e.g.) regular expressions and other transformations, and then let `readr` take another stab at parsing it."

So, all you need to do is add it at the end of your pipe:

```
df %>% ... %>% type_convert()
```

---

Alternatively, we can use `type.convert` from `base R`, which would automatically detect the column type based on the value and change it

```
df[] <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

If the constraint is to look for columns that have only one character

```
i1 <- !colSums(nchar(as.matrix(df)) > 1)
df[i1] <- type.convert(df[i1])
```

---

If we want to use `tidyverse`, there is `parse_guess` from `readr`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
df %>%
     mutate_if(all(nchar(.) == 1), parse_guess)
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction: `type_convert()` (from `readr`) is exactly meant for this scenario. So, all I needed at the end of my pipe was to add `%>% type_convert()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for `nchar` of the column in `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate_if(~all(nchar(.) == 1) & is.character(.), as.numeric)
```

Using with an example data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("ab", "bc", "de", "de", "ef"), 
                 b = as.character(1:5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 <- df %>% mutate_if(~all(nchar(.) == 1) & is.character(.), as.numeric) 

str(df1)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: chr  "ab" "bc" "de" "de" ...
# $ b: num  1 2 3 4 5
```

---

You could do the same with `map_if` as well however, it returns a list back and you need to convert it back to dataframe

```
library(purrr)

df %>% 
   map_if(~all(nchar(.) == 1) & is.character(.), as.numeric) %>% 
   as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```